# Your current search engine, 'MySQL', is not supported error after upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I am trying to update a 2.2.8 store to 2.4.3-p1. This is what I did:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update
composer update
```

After a while this was done, so I ran:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Here I am getting the **Your current search engine, 'MySQL', is not supported.** error. Makes sense since in Magento 2.2 there was no other option. So I searched a bit and found I should run

```
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
```

When I run this, I am getting **Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'queue_poison_pill' doesn't exist**. Now I am stuck here, any ideas how to fix that?

Used PHP is 7.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the missing table in Database run below query.

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `queue_poison_pill` (
  `version` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Poison Pill version.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COMMENT='Sequence table for poison pill versions';
```

Comment: Had the same idea in the meantime and it works! Thanks

Comment: @user4095519 Welcome!!

Comment: @user4095519 if it's help full to you so please upvote because other user fetch this kind of error so it's easily help